# Different image formatting for each column

Tags: typo3, typoscript

i have this code in my main template

```
tt_content.image.20 {
    rendering {
        simple {
            imageStdWrap.dataWrap = <div class="csc-textpic-imagewrap csc-textpic-single-image icon-server"> | </div>
}
}
}
```

And it works fine, but i have 4 columns and i need 3 diferent wraps with 3 diferent classes.

My question is how can i make "imageStdWrap.dataWrap" use diferent wrap depending on the column it is in?

Answer (score 0):

Copy `tt_content.image.20` on level down and switch it into a `CASE`.

```
  # save configuration for later use
temp.image < tt_content.image.20
  # override with CASE
tt_content.image.20 = CASE
tt_content.image.20 {
    # filter by column
  key.field = colPos
  default < temp.image
    # column 0 (middle)
  0 < temp.image
  0.10.wrap = Hello world ! <br />|
    # column 1 (left)
  1 < temp.image
  1.10.wrap = Hello alpha centaury ! <br />|
}
```

Comment: Thex for code, ill try it out. Will this change all of img wraps or only the ones i use with this code? I ask cause i have like 8-9 cols and i need only on 3 specific ones.

Comment: the rest will be handled by ``default``, thus if you do not change default, the other columns will be unchanged